# How to fix "Duplicate property mapping" exception?

Tags: java, hibernate

xml file to map a new table from my db but when I start the project I get a  Duplicate property mapping error that I cannot understand and resolve. Here is my hibernate cfg.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
                                         "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory name="session1">
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password"/>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/realestate</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.CharSet">utf8</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">utf8</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</property>
  <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
  <property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>
  <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.CharSet">utf8</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">utf8</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</property>
  <mapping resource="entities/users.hbm.xml"/>
  <mapping resource="entities/adminstration.hbm.xml"/>
  <mapping resource="entities/seller.hbm.xml"/>
  <mapping resource="entities/buyer.hbm.xml"/>
  <mapping resource="entities/renter.hbm.xml"/>
  <mapping resource="entities/leeser.hbm.xml"/>
  <mapping resource="entities/house.hbm.xml"/>
  <mapping resource="entities/userSellsHouse.hbm.xml"/>
  <mapping resource="entities/userRentsHouse.hbm.xml"/> 
    <mapping resource="entities/messages.hbm.xml"/> 


 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

The messages.hbm.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="entities.Message" table="MESSAGES" schema="realestate">
        <id name="messageID" type="int">
            <column name="messsageID" />

        </id>
        <property name="Date" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="Date" />
        </property>
        <property name="SenderID" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="Sender"  />
        </property>
        <property name="ReceiverID" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="Receiver"  />
        </property>
        <property name="Message" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="Message"  />
        </property>
        <property name="Theme" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="Theme"  />
        </property>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

and the Message persisent class:

```
public class Message {
    int MessageID;
    int SenderID;
    int ReceiverID;
    String date;
    String message;
    String theme;


    public int getMessageID() {
        return MessageID;
    }
    public void setMessageID(int messageID) {
        MessageID = messageID;
    }
    public int getSenderID() {
        return SenderID;
    }
    public void setSenderID(int senderID) {
        SenderID = senderID;
    }
    public int getReceiverID() {
        return ReceiverID;
    }
    public void setReceiverID(int receiverID) {
        ReceiverID = receiverID;
    }
    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
    public String getTheme() {
        return theme;
    }
    public void setTheme(String theme) {
        this.theme = theme;
    }

}
```

and here's the error

```
...
    Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Duplicate property mapping of SenderID found in entities.Messages
        at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkPropertyDuplication(PersistentClass.java:515)
        at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:505)
        at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:270)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1358)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1849)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1928)
        at database.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:15)
        ... 46 more
```

**Edit:** I tried commenting out the `<mapping resource="entities/messages.hbm.xml"/>` from the cfg file and I still get the same error.

**Edit2:** The above is from a java EE project, I copied paste everything in a simle java project and it worked fine. Any suggestion?

**Edit3:** I added the final modifier to messages class to be sure that it cannot be inherited

Comment: is any super class also there with having SenderId property, for the Message class? or any MappedSuperClass you are using,because this case can only arise when any Super class have similar attribute.

Comment: @kasharma no I dont have any superclasses at all in my project and to be sure I added final modifier to the class and the problem still exists.

Comment: Do you have property SenderID in other entities? Read this: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-5836

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please go through the following link, this might help you...

> ***[Hibernate ORMHHH-2598](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-2598)***
>
> Mapping a collection of entities from two different classes with the same collection name results in duplicate backref property exception if collection keys are not null